# Hide and show element in auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

If i click the search button in navigation bar then shown a uisearchbar and uitable need to down, then unclick the search button in navigation bar then hide the uisearchbar and table need to move top.

Please find the screenshot of my requirement

[Before clicking search icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOdXf.png)

[After clicking search icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEB5U.png)

Comment: what you want? or what are you tried?

Comment: Post ur tried code.

Comment: Below link might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/15354712/5184217

Answer (score 1):

Considering it is a table, I would implement that search panel as a custom `UITableViewCell`, and add a new section to tableView with just this cell. Then you'll have two sections in table: first with this cell, and second with the rest.

Then you can use `insertRows(at:with:)` and `deleteRows(at:with:)` to show and hide that panel (animation supported). You just need to have some data model to make sure that the state of tableView is always consistent (I will leave the appropriate `cellForRowAt` implementation on you):

```
var isCurrentlyShowingSearchBar: Bool = false

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return isCurrentlyShowingSearchBar ? 1 : 0
    case 1:
        return items.count
    default:
        fatalError()
    }
}



func showSearchBar() {
    // update model
    isCurrentlyShowingSearchBar = true
    // add cell
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}

func hideSearchBar() {
    // update model
    isCurrentlyShowingSearchBar = false
    // remove cell
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code of hide and show search bar.

you need to take reference of the top constrain like

```
@IBOutlet weak var SearchTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bar: UISearchBar!
```

set constant in viewdidload like

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SearchTop.constant = bar.frame.size.height * -1
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Then after implement the click event of the search button like

```
@IBAction func onclickSearch(_ sender: Any) {
        if SearchTop.constant == 0
        {                
            SearchTop.constant = bar.frame.size.height * -1;
        }
        else
        {
            SearchTop.constant = 0;
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```